How can I pull the most recent value from a Dataset? [code.org]
I'm working on creating a banking app in code.org for an end of unit assignment. I have created my own custom Dataset with random "transactions" and I'm trying to pull the most recent one into my code so I can get the remaining balance and set the respective text to that value. The code.org forums and documentation aren't helpful and so far I've been unable to find a solution.
I have tried a couple things so far to no avail,
// dataset vars
var id = getColumn("202401_finances", "id");
var final_amount = getColumn("202401_finances", "final_amount");    

for (var i = 0; i < id.length + 1; i++) { // "accurate" list id value finder, gets most recent transaction id
        setText("currentbalance", final_amount[i]);
}

which gives the error:
WARNING: Line: 76: setText() text parameter value (undefined) is not a uistring. 

ERROR: Line: 76: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

This is the error I keep running into and I've googled it but don't really understand why it's erroring still.
